# When is a vector considered parallel to a plane? (3D)

Tags: vector-spaces

If a plane contains a vector, is the vector still considered parallel to the plane? How can I determine when a vector is parallel  to the plane using the general equation of planes?

Comment: Yes. If a vector is contained in a plane, they are parallel. The same is true of two equal lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that the question assumes working in $3$-dimensional space.

Planes have cartesian equations of the form
$$
ax+by+cz+d=0,\quad(a,b,c)\neq(0,0,0)\qquad (\ast)
$$
and one knows that the vector $\mathbf{n}=(a,b,c)$ is ortogonal to the plane $(\ast)$. Thus a vector $\mathbf{v}=(r,s,t)$ is parallel to the plane $(\ast)$ if and only if
$$
\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{v}=ar+bs+ct=0.
$$